# Will using electron based app allow me to bypass chrome enterprise policy?

Tags: google-chrome, electron

I'm looking into porting my web app into electron but before I invest the time in doing so I would like to know if someone has enterprise chrome (https://cloud.google.com/chrome-enterprise/browser/download/#chrome-browser-policies) installed on their machine and have strict policies (no access to camera and microphone) would my electron app be affected by it?

Comment: I *really* hope you're not able to do this.  I can't think of any good reason why someone would need this capability who doesn't have malicious intent.

Comment: @RobertHarvey hehehe let's see. I absolutely don't have any malicious intent. It was just a question that came to my mind.

Comment: Idle curiosity doesn't make very good questions.  The community usually requires some level of prior research or effort be demonstrated.

Comment: I did and couldn't find anything so I figured I would post my question here.

Comment: The key word there being "demonstrated."

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out chrome enterprise policy does not affect electron based apps.